# Junit for anonymous class

Tags: junit, anonymous

```
Class ABCD{

private int startProcess(String actualPath) {
    Task<Integer>  runDriverTask = new Task<Integer>() {
    @Override
    protected Integer call() throws Exception {
        int exitCode = -1;
        return 1;
    }
  };
  ....
  ....
}
```

Some one please suggest how to write JUnits to invoke call method.
I have to do code coverage but unable to reach upto `call()` method.
What can we use ? Easymock, Power mock, Mockito or anything else.

Comment: If you need to test `runDriverTask`, you'll need to refactor it into a separate class.  But why isn't testing `startProcess(actualPath)` enough?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you want to control something that is completely out of your control.

If your "code under test" creates the objects it is dealing with (and it really doesn't matter if you do "new WhateverClass" or a "new anonymous class instance please".

So, if you have to gain control, the only **good** way is to turn to dependency injection to **provide pre-created** objects to your code under test (see [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79) for more information how/why to do that).

In addition to that, you probably could create a factory that creates such tasks for you - then you can write unit tests for the factory; that that simply create tasks and check their properties.